# Pandavro: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandavro'

Tags: python, pandas

I have installed pandavro in a virtual environment. Anytime I try to import it in jupyter I get

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandavro'` error. However, when I do a `pip freeze`, I see it has been installed. Output of pip freeze

```
fastavro==0.22.5
fastparquet==0.3.2
llvmlite==0.29.0
numba==0.45.1
numpy==1.17.2
pandas==0.25.1
pandavro==1.5.1
pyarrow==0.14.1
python-dateutil==2.8.0
python-snappy==0.5.4
pytz==2019.2
six==1.12.0
thrift==0.11.0
```

Answer (score 0):

try to launch `Jupyter` in the virtual environment.

in CMD, go to the directory where you the virtual environment is:

`\path\to\(name of the environment)\Scripts\activate`

then launch Jupyter:

`jupyter notebook`